# Prove $\phi^n = \phi F_n + \text{(another Fibonacci number)}$ using mathematical induction.

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

I need to prove the following equation using mathematical induction and using the phi values if necessary.

$\phi^n = \phi F_n + \text{(another Fibonacci number)}$

In this proof, it is kind of hard for me to prove this with the part "another Fibonacci number".

Thank you in advance.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're going to have a difficult time, because $\phi^n-\phi\cdot F_n$ isn't necessarily an integer.

Comment: OP, have you looked at $\phi^n$ for the first few $n$? It should give you an idea of the pattern, as well as how to prove it. Also, @ChristopherCarlHeckman, what makes you say that?

Comment: Hi. please explain about your problem more and your attempts to solve it. also explain about $\phi$  in your question.

Comment: Please use MathJax and state if $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: See also: [Proof by induction for golden ratio and Fibonacci sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1343821#2416474)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to show $\phi^n = \phi F_n + F_{n-1}$ by induction.

We have $F_1=1,F_0=0$, so for $n=1$ we have to prove that $\phi=\phi+0$, which is true.

Suppose it is true for $n$.
By multiplying $\phi^n = \phi F_n + F_{n-1}$ (our supposition) with $\phi$ we then have $\phi^{n+1}=\phi^2 F_n+\phi F_{n-1}$. 
Using $\phi^2=\phi+1$ the right hand side becomes $\phi F_n+F_n+\phi F_{n-1}=\phi(F_n+F_{n-1})+F_n=\phi F_{n+1}+F_n$, so the result is true for $n+1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the support given :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Assuming the conjecture true, compute $\phi^n-\phi F_n$ for increasing $n$:

$$\phi^1-\phi F_1=\phi-\phi=0,\\
\phi^2-\phi F_2=\phi^2-\phi=1,\\
\phi^3-\phi F_3=\phi^3-2\phi=\phi^3-\phi^2+\phi^2-2\phi=\phi^2-\phi=1,\\
\phi^4-\phi F_4=\phi^4-3\phi=\phi^4-\phi^3+\phi^3-\phi^2+\phi^2-3\phi=2\phi^2-2\phi=2,\\
\cdots
$$

and the pattern seems to be

$$\phi^n=\phi F_n+F_{n-1}.$$

Then sum the equality for $n$ and $n+1$, giving

$$\phi^{n+1}+\phi^{n}=\phi^{n+2}=\phi(F_{n+1}+F_n)+(F_n+F_{n-1}).$$

You can conclude now.

Comment: This helped me to prove the statement. Really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this gets a bit simpler if you look at phi.  It has a very special property, namely that

$$\phi^2 = \phi + 1 $$  Which you can generalize to n by induction since $$\phi^n = \phi^{n-1} * \phi $$

Comment: Yeah, so I can use this in the actual proof. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Right.  You can easily deduce the {some fibonacci number} as $F_{n-1}$ piece by examining the first few $\phi^n$ in this context, which makes the proof relatively straightforward.

Comment: Yes so then it becomes easy to prove the LHS to RHS of the equation. Thank you for your support.