# Show that $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^5 > 10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I have to show that $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^5 > 10$.

I've already proven that if $f_n$ is the nth Fibonnaci number, then,

$$f_{n+1} > \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n-1} $$

But I really don't get how to go from this statement to what I need to prove.

Any advices on how to take from here? Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: do you know how to expand that $(\dots)^5$ expression - brute force, but it works

Comment: You want to show that your expression is _larger_ than $10$, which if you don't want to do it directly means that you have to find something which is _smaller_ than your expression, but at the same time _larger_ than $10$. A Fibonacci number which is larger than your expression doesn't help.

Comment: @Arthur oddly, this previous statement is the previous step on the exercise.

Comment: I would recommend that if you use the brute force method that you multiply both sides by a particular number to get rid of any fractions. ... Fractions are really annoying.

Comment: $${F_n} = \frac{{{\varphi ^n} - {{( - \varphi )}^{ - n}}}}{{\sqrt 5 }} = \frac{{{{(\frac{{1 + \sqrt 5 }}{2})}^n} - {{( - \varphi )}^{ - n}}}}{{\sqrt 5 }}\\\begin{array}{l}
\varphi  = \frac{{1 + \sqrt 5 }}{2} \approx 1.61803{\mkern 1mu} 39887 \cdots \\
 - \frac{1}{\varphi } \approx  - 0.61803{\mkern 1mu} 39887 \cdots 
\end{array}$$ when $n$ go larger $${F_n} = \frac{{{{(\frac{{1 + \sqrt 5 }}{2})}^n} - {{( - \varphi )}^{ - n}}}}{{\sqrt 5 }}\sim \frac{{{{(\frac{{1 + \sqrt 5 }}{2})}^n} }}{{\sqrt 5 }}$$

Comment: $5\log_{10}\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\approx 1.044 >1$

Thus $\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^5>10$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to expand the power. This is made easier by the fact that $\phi^2 = \phi+1$.
$$
\phi^5 = (\phi+1)(\phi+1)\phi = (3\phi + 2)\phi = 5\phi+3
$$
and since it's easily shown that $\phi > 3/2$, the inequality follows.

If you want to relate to the Fibonacci numbers directly, you can also use $\phi^n = F_n\phi + F_{n-1}$ to get $\phi^5 = 5\phi+3$.

Comment: this is really nice! I still dont get why the exercise made me prove the first statement, but this is a very nice solution. thanks.

Comment: @eyeballfrog : very nice idea . would you please explain how $$\phi^n = F_n\phi + F_{n-1}$$ ?

Comment: @Khosrotash [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1757967/363566)

Comment: One answer has proved that more strongly $\phi^5>11$. To prove this using your answer, noticed that $\phi>\frac{8}{5}$ because $\sqrt{5}>\sqrt{4.84}=2.2$.

Answer (score 3):

Say $x=\sqrt{5}$. Then we have to prove:

$$1+5x+10x^2+10x^3+5x^4+x^5>64x^2 $$

or

$$1+5x+50x+25x> 29x^2$$

or $ 80x> 144$ or $5x>9$ or if we square $125>81$ which is true.

Answer (score 2):

Binomially expand
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( \frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^5 &=& \frac{1+5 \sqrt{5}  +10 \times 5 +10 \times 5 \sqrt{5}+5 \times 25 +25 \sqrt{5}}{32} \\
&=&\frac{11+5 \sqrt{5}}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now $125>121 $ square root this and we have the stronger result that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( \frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^5 > 11. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

The light brute force way is sure fire...Just using the elemetary algebra math level: $LHS > RHS \iff \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^5 > 2^5\cdot 10\iff(1+\sqrt{5})\left((1+\sqrt{5})^2\right)^2> 2^5\cdot 10\iff(1+\sqrt{5})(6+2\sqrt{5})^2> 2^5\cdot 10\iff (1+\sqrt{5})(56+24\sqrt{5}) > 320\iff 176+80\sqrt{5}> 320\iff \sqrt{5} > \dfrac{144}{80} = 1.8\iff 5 > 1.8^2 = 3.24$ which is clear. If the exponent gets sufficiently big, then the other methods will be much better for sure.